# Mongo db authentication failure in java code does not go to catch block

Tags: mongodb, authentication

I am trying to write code where mongo DB authentication is tested.

However when authentication fails the code does not reach to the catch block.

Here is the code  :

```
MongoClient client = null;  
try {  
List<MongoCredential> credentials = new ArrayList<MongoCredential>();  
credentials.add(  
    MongoCredential.createScramSha1Credential(  
       "abc",  
        "test",  
        "abc@123".toCharArray()  
    )
);  
client = new MongoClient(host,credentials, MongoClientOptions  
        .builder().connectionsPerHost(20)  
        .threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier(15)  
        .connectTimeout(5000)  
        .writeConcern(WriteConcern.ACKNOWLEDGED).build());  
} catch (Exception e) {  
client = new MongoClient(host, MongoClientOptions  
        .builder().connectionsPerHost(20)  
        .threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier(15)  
        .connectTimeout(5000)  
        .writeConcern(WriteConcern.ACKNOWLEDGED).build());  
//  e.printStackTrace();  
}  
client.getDatabase("admin").runCommand(new Document("ping",1));  

com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='abc', source='test', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties={}}
at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslAuthenticator.java:61)
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.authenticateAll(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:99)
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:44)
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115)
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:128)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This code never falls through into the catch block and runs the line just after the catch block.

Can you tell me how to handle this situation.

Comment: Catch block will be invoked only when your code fails. Authentication failure is not a strict term. Authentication process can return negative outcome, which is perfectly correct code  behavior. You should evaluate result of Authentication request and act accordingly.

Comment: If it is throwing an exception then i need to catch it do the needful but its does not allow me to catch the exception. So what return value i can expect that will help em to move ahead.